# How can I create a laravel admin & user application?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication, eloquent

I am working on a laravel application that includes a user login at the root website (example.com/login) and a admin login for content administrators (example.com/admin/login).

I would like to accomplish this by having 2 separate databases:

The admin database is set and configured as the default database, where I have a 'users' table with admin user specific columns.

The user database is set and configured as my secondary database, it also has a 'users' table but with normal user specific columns.

I want to configure a separate authentication for users (admins) at 'example.com/admin' and users (normal users) for 'example.com'.

I'm not really sure how to do this.

I don't know how to configure my auth controllers, should I create a subfolder for admin to copy & reroute my auth controllers in there (App/Http/Admin/Auth) and keep my original auth folder for my normal users login (App/Http/Auth)?

I also couldn't find the answer on how to make 2 user models, each connecting to a users table, but from different databases. (I already configured the 2 connections and migrated the tables).

I know one solution would be to create 2 laravel applications, but what I'm trying to accomplish is to do this in one. Any solution is strongly appreciated.

Comment: why not just both admin and user share the same table?, and why 2 databases ?

Comment: @Hussein Not the same table because my admin users have different properties then my normal users (My admin users will have 'image_URL' column to store a profile picture and a 'level' column to determine what they can manage on the site, while my normal normal users will not need these properties but have different properties. 2 databases is important for me, because I wish to reuse the admin part of this projects for future projects, by just removing this projects specific database, and creating another one for my next project.

Comment: you can save yourself the hustle of having 2 tables and authentication and stuff later, just have 1 table and when you create a user later set the image_url to null, & for the 2 database problem, for future projects just copy the migration, it's not good to have 2 databases where the other one not related to the project